# Uploading image from url to multipart/form-data endpoint

Tags: node.js, post, request, image-uploading

I have an endpoint that only accepts images uploaded as multipart MIME content in the request body. This is no problem if I have the images downloaded and re-uploaded, but I want to upload an image from a url elsewhere, I'm at a loss as to what to do.

Are there any ideas to handling this situation without downloading the image locally to reupload?

I've been trying to make use of the request library to get the image data contents and append it as form data in my subsequent upload POST request, but that doesn't work either...

```
request.get(IMAGE_URL, function(err, res, body) {
    var imageData = body;
    var r = request.post(UPLOAD_URL, function(err2, res2, body2)  {
       //** blah **//
    }
    var form = r.form();
    form.append('data', imageData);
}
```

Comment: Sorted this out! The last line was missing a parameter for filename! `form.append('data', imageData, 'image.jpg')`